# How set com.ibm.websphere.ssl.SSLSocketFactory for Spring RestTemplate?

Tags: spring, websphere, resttemplate, sslsocketfactory

I'd like to customize SslSocketFactory used by Spring RestTemplate and its httpclient into ClientHttpRequestFactory: I want to use ssl socket factory provided by websphere application server. I'm using Spring 4.3.9 and WAS 8.5.
Could you please help me?

Comment: can help, let me know if you still looking for this setup?